# SQL statement results have a multiplier for the first three rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am having an issue with MySQL I have a SQL statement that is as follows:

```sql
Select Products.ProductID, Products.ModelNumber, Products.SerialNumber, Products.Description, Products.ListPrice, 
        Sum(OrderDetails.Quantity) AS QuantityOrdered, Sum(Inventory.Quantity) AS QuantityOnHand

From Products
LEFT JOIN OrderDetails USING(ProductID)
LEFT JOIN Inventory USING(ProductID)

group by Products.ProductID, Products.ModelNumber, Products.SerialNumber, Products.Description, Products.ListPrice;
```

The SQL statement is working fine except the first three rows that get returned have a multiplier on the `Sum(OrderDetails.Quantity) AS QuantityOrdered` column. The first row has a multiplier of 4, the second has a multiplier of 3, and the third row has one of 2. Every other row is just fine and the `Sum(Inventory.Quantity) AS QuantityOnHand` column returns the proper numbers, no multiplier.

I have edited the values in the `OrderDetails` table that pertain to the `ProdcutID`'s that match up to the first three rows. I have changed the quantities to 1 for each of those and I get 4, 3, and 2 respectively.

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected results?

Comment: You've got multiple rows through the `LEFT JOIN`, I'd wager.

Comment: You're creating a cross product between the 3 tables. So it multiplies `OrderDetails.Quantity` by the number of `Inventory` rows that have that `ProductID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need separate count(), try subquery like this:

```
Select Products.ProductID, Products.ModelNumber, Products.SerialNumber, Products.Description, Products.ListPrice
, (select Sum(Quantity) from OrderDetails where ProductID = Products.ProductID) AS QuantityOrdered
, (select Sum(Quantity) from Inventory where ProductID = Products.ProductID) AS QuantityOnHand
From Products
```

or if you need only products from Order:

```
Select Products.ProductID, Products.ModelNumber, Products.SerialNumber, Products.Description, Products.ListPrice
, Sum(Quantity) AS QuantityOrdered
, (select Sum(Quantity) from Inventory where ProductID = Products.ProductID) AS QuantityOnHand
From Products JOIN OrderDetails USING(ProductID)
group by Products.ProductID, Products.ModelNumber, Products.SerialNumber, Products.Description, Products.ListPrice
```

Answer (score 1):

You are aggregating along two different dimensions, resulting in a Cartesian product of the inventory and order details for each product -- no wonder the `sum()` is off.

A typical way to solve this is to aggregate *before the join* along each dimension:

```
Select p.ProductID, p.ModelNumber, p.SerialNumber, p.Description, p.ListPrice, 
       od.QuantityOrdered, i.QuantityOnHand
From Products p LEFT JOIN
     (select od.ProductId, Sum(od.Quantity) as QuantityOrdered
      from OrderDetails
      group by od.ProductdId
     ) od
     USING (ProductID) LEFT JOIN
     (select i.ProductId, Sum(Inventory.Quantity) as QuantityOnHand
      from Inventory i
      group by i.ProductId
     ) i
     USING (ProductID);
```

Comment: This works but required some editing. Replacing p with Products and such

Comment: @PerLarsen . . . I'm not sure what you mean by that.  Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.